# Read file path sections to model

Tags: java, java-8

Given I have the following `Domain` which models a File to be delivered if you like:

```
public class Report {

    private String reportId;
    private String reportName;
    private String client;
    private String format;
    private Date cobDate;
    private String filePath;

}

public enum ReportType {

    PNL_REPORT("11", "pnlreport"),
    BALANCE_SHEET("20", "balance"),

    private final String reportId;
    private final String name;

    private ReportType(String reportId, String name) {
        this.reportId = reportId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and given I have the below `Service` implementation:

```
@Service
public class FileService {

    @Autowired
    private FileRepository fileRepository;


    public List<Report> getReport(String filePattern, String format) {

        List<Report> reportDeliverables = new ArrayList<>();

        List<File> filesToSend = fileRepository.getFilesToSend(sourcePath, filePattern, format);

        \\C:\pathToReports\ClientABC\COB28Sep2017\pnlreport.pdf

        \\return list of report objects, initialised. 
    }

}
```

I am using Java 8 and would like to know how I can convert efficiently each `File` objects in the list `filesToSend` to `Report` fields as follows:

reportID -> derive from Enum looking at id (**name** matches filename without suffix)

reportName -> pnlreport.pdf

client -> clientABC

cobDate-> 28-SEP-2017

format -> pdf

filePath -> C:\pathToReports\ClientABC\COB28Sep2017\pnlreport.pdf

The path will always have source followed by client, cob date, then the name of report file.

Comment: I don't understand how do you create reportID. Other info can be extracted from file path with regex groups. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: it is a mapping to the `ReportType` enum `reportID`, dervied from lookup to `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I undestand your problem there is its solution. Notice that regex in ReportFile satisfies only windows-like file path. For other OS there would be other regexes needed.

```
enum ReportType {

    PNL_REPORT("11", "pnlreport"),
    BALANCE_SHEET("20", "balance");

    private final String reportId;
    private final String name;

    ReportType(String reportId, String name) {
        this.reportId = reportId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    static ReportType fromName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(reportType -> reportType.name.equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return reportId;
    }
}

class ReportFile {

    private static final Pattern WINDOWS_REGEX =
        Pattern.compile(".+\\\\(Client[^\\\\]+)\\\\COB([^\\\\]+)\\\\([^\\\\.]+).([^\\\\.]+)");

    private static final Pattern UNIX_REGEX =  
        Pattern.compile(".+/(Client[^/]+)/COB([^/]+)/([^/.]+).([^/.]+)");

    private final File file;

    public ReportFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    Report toReport() {
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        Matcher matcher = WINDOWS_REGEX.matcher(filePath);

        if (!matcher.find()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid path for report: " + filePath);
        }

        String client = matcher.group(1);
        Date cobDate;
        try {
            LocalDate cobLocalDate =
                LocalDate.parse(matcher.group(2), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dMMMy").withLocale(Locale.US));
            cobDate = Date.from(cobLocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        String reportName = matcher.group(3);
        String id = ReportType.fromName(matcher.group(3)).getId();
        String extension = matcher.group(4);

        return new Report(
            id, reportName, client, extension, cobDate, filePath
        );
    }
}

class Ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Report> reportDeliverables = new ArrayList<>();

        List<File> filesToSend = ImmutableList.of(
            new File("C:\\pathToReports\\ClientABC\\COB28Sep2017\\pnlreport.pdf")
        );

        System.out.println(filesToSend.stream()
            .map(ReportFile::new)
            .map(ReportFile::toReport)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I've managed to translate `ReportFile` into a `Component` class and reading in regex from config. Could you please update your answer to include unix path regex and not strip out string "client"

Comment: I've added unix regex but client string is not stripped out. `(Client[^/]+)` means that Client string will be inside the first group.

Comment: @user2781389 if it solves your problem, please accept this answer.